# I need a help to solve Hackerrank's data structure challenge

Tags: arrays, data-structures, accumulate

I was trying to solve a data structure question from Hackerrank and i could not figure it out. Actually, i could not understand exact logic lying under problem.Below is a link to question question.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush

Comment: Problem deal with number ranges, so look at interval/range data structures

Comment: Sir, I tried to solve that but I could not figured out by my way . I think there is another logic on this problem.

Comment: You have to show your efforts to get a chance for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not optmized, so will not pass all tests cases for python (10s timenout), but you can have an idea.

```
n, m = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
numbers = []
for i in range(m+1):
    numbers.append(0)

for i in range(m):
    a , b , k = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
    for j in range(b - a + 1):
        numbers[a + j -1] = numbers[a + j - 1] + k

print(max(numbers))
```